# How to reduce the white space under my post on blogger for mobile device

Tags: css

I have a white space under the mobile version of my blogger template which doesn't appear on desktop.

How can I remove this white space so that the mobile version looks exactly the same as the desktop one?

https://lj-00ps.blogspot.com/

Thanks in advance...

I have tried inserting this but it didn't work:

```
.footer-outer {display:none;}
```

Comment: I am not getting which white space about you talking. can you please explain more?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please clarify your question more

Comment: Okay. If you look at my website on a desktop there is no white space under the orange box. But if you look at it on a mobile device, there is a huge massive white space underneath the orange box. It doesn't look good and it also makes the orange box look tiny. I would like my website to look the same on a mobile phone as it does on a desktop. Thank you, gentlemen.

Answer (score 0):

Set height 100vh to your container.

```
.content-inner{
  height: 100vh;
 }
```

Comment: Hi Ram, thank you, I tried that but it doesn't change how it looks on a mobile device- the white space is still there.